# Print fields from logs with time/date and value

Tags: text-processing, awk

Using only grep and awk is it possible to print MMM DD HH:MM:SS plus another field (e.g. SRC)  from a log file? So on a large log file extract only date, time and SRC...

Sample info from log:

```
Oct 19 21:13:00 server kernel: [ 6457.382677] PING:IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:05:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00 SRC=192.168.0.101 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=52472 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=2438 SEQ=3
Oct 19 21:13:01 server kernel: [ 6458.385884] PING:IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:05:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00 SRC=192.168.0.101 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=52719 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=2438 SEQ=4
```

Expected output:

```
Oct 19 21:13:00 SRC=192.168.0.101
```

Comment: without knowing the input, how are we supposed to answer this?

Comment: 1. Yes, awk can print a subset of the fields from an input line. If you want a detailed answer, you'll have to provide details about exactly what you want, including sample input and output.  2. If you're using `awk`, you don't need to use `grep`. In almost all cases, piping grep's output into awk is a Useless Use Of Grep.  awk can do ERE matching (like `egrep`/`grep -E`).  e.g. `awk -F, '/PROTO=TCP/ {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i=="SRC"){print $i}}}'`

Comment: BTW, what do you mean by *"but I do not know how to add the date at the beginning?"* ?   does the log file not have date & time field(s)?   If not, what date/time do you want to print?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, hopefully the above makes more sense

Comment: Perl? Raku? If you eventually need to produce ISO-8601 format, you could save some coding effort. https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html

Answer (score 2):

`awk` uses space as field separator by default so just printing the right columns will do it.

```
 $ cat file.txt
 
 Oct 19 21:13:00 server kernel: [ 6457.382677] PING:IN=eth0 OUT=
 MAC=00:00:00:00:00:05:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00 SRC=192.168.0.101
 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=52472 DF
 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=2438 SEQ=3
```

```
$ awk '{ print $1, $2, $3, $11 }' file.txt
```

output:

```
Oct 19 21:13:00 SRC=192.168.0.101
```

Comment: Thank you Serve, this is a great help